# I need to mark a matching set of integers for a mathematical check with fractions

Tags: c++

what I'm trying to achieve is to make some stuff with a certain amout of non-decimal fractions such as 1/2, 1/3 etc. And since the c++ language, at least as far as I know, can't handle automatically such fractions, the decision would be to present them to the engine as a numerator and a denominator and to fulfill the actions single-handedly with the 2 values under and above the line. The thing in my case is, that I don't want to double check the same fraction with the algorhythm, that I'm using with them, twice and would like to tell the compiler to skip the current step of the loop if the A value (the fraction is A/B) has already been an X value and the B value has already been an Y value at the same time. I don't know if I've explained that understandable, so I'm gonna show it with a code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int g_iNumerators[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}; //Here are all of my possible numerators
const int g_iDenominators[] = {1, 3, 9};         //And here are all of the denominators

// The simple way I'm reducing fractions (stil a newbie tho :D)
int reduce_fraction(int &a, int &b)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= a; i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0 && b%i==0)
        {
            a /= i;
            b /= i;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i, a;
    int numerator, denominator;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(g_iNumerators)/sizeof(g_iNumerators[0]); i++)
    {
        numerator = g_iNumerators[i];

        for(a = 0; a < sizeof(g_iDenominators)/sizeof(g_iDenominators[0]); a++)
        {
            denominator = g_iDenominators[a];

            //Here I get all the combinations of A/B, all the possible numerators divided by all the possible denominators
            //The thing is, that I want to not do the stuff again if for example I've already done it with 2/1 and should do it again with 6/3

            //So after I've reduced the fraction 6/3 it becomes 2/1 again, but I don't want to repeat the function with the same fraction.
        reduce_fraction(numerator, denominator);

            //How to prevent that?
            if(...)
                continue;

            //Code goes on....
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class out of it and implement the == operator:

```
class Fraction{

  int num;
  int den;

  Fraction(int n, int d){
    //probably a good idea to find a better reduce-algorithm here
    //maybe with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/gcd ?
  }

  bool operator==(Fraction& other){
    //comparing fractions might be inexact for floats.
    //return (1.*num)/den == (1.*other.num)/other.den;

    //this one on the opposite relies on a working reduction in the constructor
    return (num==other.num) && (den==other.den);
  }

}
```

you can then store instances of this inside a `std::unordered_set<Fraction>` and later check if an equal element is already present. Or just fill a set with the instances you want to use and then use them in a second loop after you filled the set.

Using a class also provides the benefit, that you can implement addition, multiplication and so on inside your class by just overloading the corresponding operators.

Comment: Since when can floating point values be compared for *exact* equality?

Comment: If there's a proper reduce-algorithm in the constructor, you can also compare num and den directly, comparing the fraction was just meant to be an example. But you are right, i'll edit it.

Comment: @Anedar Thanks a lot! I'm such a newbie and was totally unaware of the possibility to use a whole new class to make my stuff easier. I guess I should rewrite the whole code using the new class, as soon as I get common enough with its right usage. I've also read the documentation about unordered_set, I think that's what's gonna be a bit harder for me. As soon as I'm finished, I'll update the code for anyone else who needs something like that. If I have some troubles, I will share them here. Btw, any further suggestions are wellcome as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also couldn't find the right library for that experimental::gcd, so I guess I'll drop that or leave it for later, since it's working as it is now. I know it's not the optimized best way to do it, but I'll think about that later.

Comment: I've succeeded to do it all, now I have a problem with the unordered_set<>, I think it's some kind of a problem because of the custom class I'm trying to use as a hash for the set. There are about 6 pages of errors and I'm getting sent to `functional_hash.h` with the error `...functional_hash.h|60|error: static assertion failed: std::hash is not specialized for this type|`

Comment: Already done, succeeded to implement my custom class with by injecting a brand new hash into `namespace std`, then I had to make my operator a constant value, so that it could compile...